# Java Collections.sort(List<T> list,Comparator<? super T> c)

Tags: java, sorting, collections

i have to implement this test:

```
package it.unica.pr2.test;

import it.unica.pr2.abitazioni.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
/*import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;*/

public class TestAbitazioni /*extends Application*/ {


  public static void main(String[] args)  /*public void start(Stage primaryStage) */{
        // C
        Immobile casa = new Casa();
        List<Ambiente> c2 = casa;

        // C+
        casa.add(new Bagno(10));                // 10 mq
        casa.add(new Cucina(20));               // 20 mq
        casa.add(new CameraDaLetto(25));        // 25 mq
        casa.add(new CameraDaLetto(15));        // 15 mq
        casa.add(new Corridoio(12));            // 12 mq

        assert casa.superficie() == 10 + 20 + 25 + 15 + 12;

        assert casa.bilocale() == false;        // i bi locali hanno solo 1 cucina 1 bagno 1 camera da letto (no altri ambienti)

        // B
        Bagno bagno = new Bagno(13);
        assert bagno.toString().equals("Questo ambiente occupa 13mq");
        Cucina cucina = new Cucina(26);
        assert cucina.toString().equals("Questo ambiente occupa 26mq");

        Collections.sort(casa);                 // sort by dimension
        assert casa.get(0).getSuperficie() == 10;
        assert casa.get(1).getSuperficie() == 12;
        assert casa.get(2).getSuperficie() == 15;
        assert casa.get(3).getSuperficie() == 20;
        assert casa.get(4).getSuperficie() == 25;

        // A
        Collections.sort(casa, new StanzeByType()); // prima cucine, poi camere da letto, poi bagni, poi qualsiasi altro tipo; a parita' di tipo, dal piu' piccolo al piu' grande

        assert casa.get(0).getSuperficie() == 20;
        assert casa.get(1).getSuperficie() == 15;
        assert casa.get(2).getSuperficie() == 25;
        assert casa.get(3).getSuperficie() == 10;
        assert casa.get(4).getSuperficie() == 12;
        /*
        // A+
        casa.mostraCasa();        
         * 
         */
    }
/*
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        launch(args);
    }    */
}
```

Collections.sort(casa, new StanzeByType()) the problem is here, how i implement a class constructor here for sort the collection by type?
if the italian language is a problem i'll translate the source.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Are you looking for anonymous classes?

Comment: it would be easier if you translate. do your class Immobile or subclass Casa implements comparable? If not please take a look to this link: [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your StanzeByType class should look like this in order to sort by type...Hope this may help

```
public class StanzeByType implements Comparator<Ambiente>{

@Override
public int compare(Ambiente amiAmbiente, Ambiente otherAmbiente) {

    return amiAmbiente.getType().compareTo(otherAmbiente.getType());
}

}
```